# Sync with time server on iPad (date/time) via WiFi?

Tags: ipad, wifi, time

We are deploying iPads in an enterprise environment. We have a specific use case where we will use an app for internal use only. We tried to completely lock down access, but we see it is too restrictive. For example, the iPad needs to talk with a time server to sync the date and time. Does anyone know the specifics about what servers the time sync occurs with? Is it just apple.com? Or perhaps a set of time servers?

Comment: Can you unblock UDP Port 123? I believe iOS uses the Network Time Protocol to update time, and NTP uses port 123. Also, try unblocking * .apple.com, as it * could * be using time.apple.com

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct about port 123. Could you post your comment an answer and I will mark it as answer? https://andyparkernz.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/allowing-your-devices-to-talk-to-apple-part-2/ http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6175?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944

123 UDP Network Time Protocol (NTP) 1305    ntp Date & Time preferences, network time server synchronization, Apple TV network time server sync